# Пагинация для для страниц а не постов WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Скажите а можно ли сделать пагинацию для страниц, не для постов, создаю страницы через родительскую, и вывожу тут проблем никаких, но мне нужно ограничить вывод этих страниц по 3, то есть сделать пагинацию, это возможно или нужно переделывать под посты?

Comment: Возможно. Поищите на английском. Много решений есть

Comment: Конечно можно сделать, но придется писать небольшой велосипед, думаю не сложно придумать

Answer (score 0):

Для [страниц](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) не может быть пагинации, тк они не проходят через цикл и у них нет виртуальных страниц ленты.